# Javaswift JOSS best practice for AccountFactory

Tags: openstack-swift

Have an application that puts, gets and deletes objects to/from an openstack swift object store. I use JOSS as the java api. What is the best practice for using the AccountFactory object? Should it be instantiated and held for the life of the application? It is pretty expensive to instantiate.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an Account in SWIFT, you are holding a stateful session. It will remember the authentication token and pass that on with every request to the Swift container. Normally, Keystone tokens are valid for 24 hours, but this may differ per Swift implementation. So it really depends on the life time of the project.

So if you are using swift for a security critical component, I would prefer to authenticate every time you perform an action to save your application from security vulnerability. In case it is not a security critical component then you can have it in your code instantiated for the time period of the keystone tokens change. But you need to re-instantiate it every time the keystone token changes.

To know about JOSS authentication you can refer here :
http://joss.javaswift.org/authentication.html#architecture